# Save downloaded file with multiple subfolders on iOS - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, save

My project requires to download a Gzip file from the Internet, that contains multiple subfolders in a tree structure and images on the last folders, and save all the structure with subfolders and images on Documents Directory.

```
Root_Folder/
   Folder_Level_1/
      Folder_Level_2/
         Image
      Folder_Level_2/
         Image
   Folder_Level_1/
      Folder_Level_2/
         Image
      Folder_Level_2/
         Image
```

Download and compression work fine, the problem is when I try to save the content on the documents directory, as it threats all the content if it was a single file.

```
NSData *data = ...uncompressed file...
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FileName"];

BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path
                                                       contents:data
                                                       attributes:nil];
```

I don't even know if it's possible to save the structure of subfolders I am trying to save... If it's possible, what's wrong on my code and what's the proper way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to untar the ungzipped data. A gzip file only contains a single file. Typically you tar a group of files and then gzip the tar file.

Comment: I am downloading a `.gz` file, do you mean I should download `.tar.gz` instead to be able to unzip folders?

Comment: I don't know what you are downloading. You need to determine what you have. Get the file on your computer. Uncompress the gzip file. Now see what you have. Once you know what you have, you will know what you need to do next.

Comment: I've got a folder with multiple subfolders compressed in a `.gz` file (I also tried `.tar.gz`). When I uncompress them on my computer everything is fine with both types.